# Well-definition of a function from rationals to rationals

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

This is admittedly a homework question, but it seems erroneous to me.

> Define the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ as the set of equivalence classes on $\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\})$ corresponding to the equivalence relation $\sim$, where
>
> $$(a,b)\sim (c,d) \Leftrightarrow ad = bc$$
>
> Show that $f: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ given by $f([(a,b)]_\sim) = [(a+b,b)]_\sim$ is not well-defined.

But here is a proof (I think) that $f$ is well-defined:

$[(a,b)]_\sim = [(c,d)]_\sim \Rightarrow ad = bc$ by definition of $\sim$

$\Rightarrow ad = cb$, by commutativity of multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$

$\Rightarrow ad + bd = cb+db$, by an addition property of equality and commutativity of multiplication

$\Rightarrow (a+b)d = (c+d)b$, by right distributivity of multiplication over addition

$\Rightarrow [(a+b,b)]_\sim=[(c+d,d)]_\sim$, by definition of $\sim$

$\Rightarrow f([(a,b)]_\sim) = f([(c,d)]_\sim)$, by definition of $f$.

Therefore $f$ is well-defined by the definition of a well-defined function. $\Box$

Is my proof incorrect?

Comment: Looks correct to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. What the map $f$ essentially does is simply adding $1$.